# Is it possible to create one configuration for some classes with Orika mapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, orika

I try to config Orika mapper. I have 5 entities and 5 DTO. My configuration work true, but I can't find any information about how to configure mapper for different classes. So is it possible to create one configuration for some classes or I should create configuration for every pair of classes?

```
@Configuration 
public class MapperConfig implements OrikaMapperFactoryConfigurer {

@Bean
DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
}

@Bean
DefaultMapperFactory.MapperFactoryBuilder<?, ?> orikaMapperFactoryBuilder() {
    DefaultMapperFactory.Builder orikaMapperFactoryBuilder = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder();
    return orikaMapperFactoryBuilder;
}

@Bean
public MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory(DefaultMapperFactory.MapperFactoryBuilder<?, ?> orikaMapperFactoryBuilder) {
    MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory = orikaMapperFactoryBuilder.build();
    this.configure(orikaMapperFactory);
    return orikaMapperFactory;
}

public void configure(MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory) {
    orikaMapperFactory.classMap(Author.class, AuthorDto.class)
            .byDefault()
            .register();
}

@Bean
public MapperFacade orikaMapperFacade(MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory) {
    MapperFacade orikaMapperFacade = orikaMapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    return orikaMapperFacade;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to register **mapper** for other two pairs of classes in **configure** method

Example:

```
public void configure(MapperFactory orikaMapperFactory) {
      orikaMapperFactory.classMap(Author.class, AuthorDto.class)
      .byDefault()
      .register();
      orikaMapperFactory.classMap(A.class, B.class)
      .byDefault()
      .register();
}
```